# Restart the conditional formatting in excel when a different group is detected

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[1]I have different groups having some values in the following format

```
Group|Value
1    |1
1    |0
1    |-1
2    |1
2    |0
3    |1
3    |-1
3    |0
```

I am trying to apply conditional formatting on these values based on groups. The values are sorted based on groups and they are to be formatted separately for each group. This cannot be done manually because the excel file is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula in CF:

```
=ISODD($A1)
```

[image]

Comment: What if I had Group names as some strings?

Comment: @saikrishna If group names are strings, then simplest solution will be making helper column (say C) with formula ```=IF(A2<>A1;C1+1;C1)``` and using that for CF.

Comment: I want this to be a 3 color scale for each group separately based only on values in the group. Is it possible?

Comment: @saikrishna Hard to say. Edit your question and add desired result for your sample.

Comment: not able to add a picture. Is there any other way I can send you the picture and an explanation for it?

Comment: @saikrishna then share sample file in OneDrive or GoogleSheets and post link here.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zerrnSPtXRLjQR-4_0i0S2ibTwZP7hNETUK132U-qu4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @saikrishna No, unfortunately I can't offer a solution for the three color scale.